# NgAnimate not working - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-animate

I can't understand how to get my ngAnimate to work with this view:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5eW6aN?p=preview

I am expecting the links containing the word "Link" to make the grey box slide out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**ng-animate attribute is deprecated in 1.2.**

In 1.2 you define the appropriate CSS classes using a special naming convention. If you want a specific name like 'animation', you need to add that class to the element you want to animate.

As long as you have the correct CSS classes, some directives will be animated automatically. Which ones can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

This is the reason your animation works in your second example when just defining the ".ng-enter" class. This would however automatically animate all directives that support the enter animation.

I have updated your first example to make it work with the class named 'animation':

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="animation">{{item}}</li>
```

With CSS:

```
   .animation {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.animation.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

see this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/J0qJEMmwdzqXzu733fJf?p=preview